# Updating mysql row not working properly (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What i'm trying to do is to update a mysql row ( in this case, only the username) just the way phpMyAdmin handles it ( click on input field, change value, press enter ).

As far as I can see, I have no errors in my code. I also don't see any php errors coming up after submitting it.

Here is the code for main page:

```html
// Here, I select the rows I need to be displayed first.

<?php $q="SELECT gebruikersnaam,wachtwoord,id FROM login WHERE rollen !=1 AND rollen !=2" ; $stmt=$ conn->prepare( $q ); $stmt->execute(); ?> // Table to show the rows
<div id="box">
  <!-- Table -->
  <center>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style='color:#e20363;'>ID
            <br>
          </th>
          <th>Gebruikersnaam
            <br>
          </th>
          <th>Wachtwoord
            <br>
          </th>
          <th>Actie
            <br>
          </th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
</div>

<?php while($row=$ stmt->fetch()){ $id=$row['id']; echo "
<tr>"; echo "
  <td style='color:#e20363; text-align:center;'>{$row['id']}</td>"; // Here, I made the input field show the mysql row and made a form to submit when I press enter echo "
  <form action='update.php' method='post'>"; echo "
    <td>
      <input type='text' value='{$row[' gebruikersnaam ']}' name='gebruikersnaam'>
    </td>"; echo "</form>"; echo "
  <td style='text-align:center; padding:10px;'>
    <input type='text' value='{$row[' wachtwoord ']}' name='password'>
  </td>"; echo '
  <center>
    <td>
      <a href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">
        <img id="remove_user" src="images/remove.png" width="60px" style="padding:13px;">
      </a>
    </td>
  </center>'; echo "</tr>"; } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

After user clicks submit, update.php tries to handle the update query.
Here is my update.php code:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username'])){



$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$database = 'users';
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $pass);



$sql = "UPDATE `login` SET `gebruikersnaam` = :username";
 
//Prepare our UPDATE SQL statement.
$statement = $pdo-> prepare($sql);
 
//Bind our value to the parameter :id.
$statement->bindValue(':username', $_POST['username']);
  
//Execute our UPDATE statement.
$update = $statement->execute();

if($update){
header('Location: account_verwijderen.php'); 
}
};
?>
```

All seems to be working fine. but when I try to update the query ( press enter , it does send me to update.php , but seems to be doing nothing as my redirect code to the main page doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: No `name=username` attribute in your form!!

Comment: I see 1 error which I corrected, but the code still doesnt work:

if(isset($_POST['username'])){  is looking for a username, and I had another name for the input field. I changed the input field name to 'username'. code still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably that you are binding ':username' but should be binding 'username' - you don't need the colon in the bind statement.

You should define the date type your binding too at so:

```
bindValue('id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

try adding an else after `if (success) { bit that fires die(PDOStatement->errorInfo());` and you'll see any errors in the SQL syntax. remove it or add to file logging before you go live though.

Also

You have no 'where' statement in the update query so it needs to be:

```
UPDATE `login` SET `gebruikersnaam` = :username where id = :id;
```

This means you need to be capturing the ID of the login from the POST too. Without it the query will update all the records in the table.

Comment: Sweet. that worked like a charm. Indeed, I forgot to use a 'where' statement. 

I still have bindValue like this ->  ":username" and it is still working though.
Thank you very much.